# Upper bounds of integrals of $1/x^r$

Tags: integration, inequality

I am trying to get bound  for the following integral
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x|^r}dx, \mbox{for } 1\leq r< \infty
$$
In particular, the bound of the form $\frac{constant}{r}$.

Sorry, we can omit the absolute value. And probably consider interval $(a,\infty)$ for some $a$ very close to 0.
So, the integral is 
$$
\int_a^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^r}dx, \mbox{for } 1\leq r< \infty
$$

Comment: Do you  want $\int_a^\infty {1\over |x|^r}\,dx$ for some $a>0$? As it stands, the integral never converges.

Comment: I think that the absolute value signs can be omitted, or should we interpret it as a complex integral?

Comment: I would assume that you can find the exact value of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first do some inital work. Here we first safely assume $r>1$.
Then our integral turns into (We exclude the limits for now)

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^r} \, \text{d}x = \left[ \frac{1}{1-r} x^{1-r} \right]_{0}^{\infty} $$

Quite easily we can see that since $r>0$

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1-r}x^{1-r} = 0 $$

This is quite good! Now we know that

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^r} \, \text{d}x = \left[ \frac{1}{1-r} x^{1-r} \right]_{0}^{\infty} = 0 - \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{1-r}x^{1-r}$$

The problem is that this last limit does not exist for any values of r. It simply tends to $- \infty$ for all values of $r$.

Let us now plot the problem for a few values of r, to really strike home the point

[image: Illustration]

As we can see the problem is how these functions behave at values very close to zero and very close to infinity. In a nuttshell, the problem with evaluating this integral is that

$ \frac{1}{x^r} $

Approaches $\infty$ at a faster rate when r> increases but, approaches 0 at a slower rate when r increases. Similarly

Approaches $\infty$ at a slower rate when r decreases but, approaches 0 at a faster rate when r increases. As can be seen from the graph.

Although a similar integral that does converge is

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^r} \, \text{d}x = \frac{1}{r - 1} $$

So to sum up

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^r} \, \text{d}x = -\infty $$

when $1<r<\infty$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $x\mapsto \dfrac1{x^{r-1}}$ is $x\mapsto-\dfrac{r-1}{x^r}$, hence, for every $r\gt1$ and $a\gt0$,
$$
\int_a^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^r}=\left[-\frac1{(r-1)x^{r-1}}\right]_{x=a}^{x=+\infty}=\frac1{(r-1)a^{r-1}}.$$
There is no upper bound independent on $a\gt0$. If $a=0$ or if $r=1$, the integral diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The integral is not bounded.

For r=1 the primitive function of the integrand is log(x) which diverges at 0 and infinity.

For r>1 the primitive function of the integrand is $\frac{1-r}{x^{r-1}}$ which diverges at 0.